# Base-change of schemes over number rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $S$ be a finite set of maximal ideals in $  O_K$, where $O_K$ is the ring of integers of some number field $K$. Define $A= O_K[S^{-1}]$.

Let $X$ be an arbitrary $A$-scheme. Consider the scheme  $X_A=X\times_{\mathbb Z} A$ as an $A$-scheme via the second projection.

Is $X_A$ the disjoint union of at most $[K:\mathbb Q]$ copies of $X$?

Edit: I rewrote the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Question 1: This is just abstract nonsense: if a morphism factors through a monomorphism, then pulling back (or, base change, if you like) along that monomorphism doesn't do anything.

Comment: Dear Zhen Lin, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

The answers to question 2 are "no".  Take $R = A = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$, and let $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$.  There is no ring isomorphism between $A \otimes A$ and $A \oplus A$.